# javac is not working. error: file not found: Sum.java always pops up when i want to compile the program. Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: windows, javac, file-not-found

[image]
Here you see the problem

Im the new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the compiler from the wrong directory. The file path actually is: C:\Users\User\documents\Sum.java.

Either run `javac documents\Sum.java` or switch to the "documents" directory by doing `cd documents`.